# What is concise way of deep-copying a 2D MutableList?

Tags: list, collections, kotlin, deep-copy

The element already implemented deep copying.

```
fun <T : DeepCopiable> f(a: MutableList<MutableList<T>>) {
    val copied = a.map { it.map { it.deepCopy() }.toMutableList() }.toMutableList()
    ...
}
```

I am using this kind of code, but it seems verbose.

Comment: Writing `f(a)` for your copying operation does not seem very verbose.

Comment: @IngoKegel disagree, if the interface method was named slightly different, the intent of the code (deep-copy) would not be immediately clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to restrictions in the type system, this problem cannot be generalized to a single functon without bypassing type safety (and due to JVM type erasure you definitely don't want to go *that* rabbit hole when generics are involved¹).

However, you can write a *chain* of extension functions implementing a deep-copy pattern, delegating to the previous function for every increase in dimension, in a type safe matter:

```
private typealias I<E> = Iterable<E>
private typealias Copy<E> = (E) -> E
private inline fun <T, R> I<T>.mapToMutable(transform: (T) -> R): I<R> = mapTo(mutableListOf(), transform)
fun <E> I<E>.deepCopy1(c: Copy<E>) = mapToMutable { c(it) }
fun <E> I<I<E>>.deepCopy2(c: Copy<E>) = mapToMutable { it.deepCopy1(c) }
fun <E> I<I<I<E>>>.deepCopy3(c: Copy<E>) = mapToMutable { it.deepCopy2(c) }
fun <E> I<I<I<I<E>>>>.deepCopy4(c: Copy<E>) = mapToMutable { it.deepCopy3(c) }
fun <E> I<I<I<I<I<E>>>>>.deepCopy5(c: Copy<E>) = mapToMutable { it.deepCopy4(c) }
```

Due to JVM type erasure, the functions need different names (`@JVMName` does not help due to type interference ambiguity²). Type aliases are used to prevent horizontal space explosion³, and the function set is uncoupled from the deep-copiable interface via a generic copy function parameter.

Example usage:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    data class IntHolder(var value: Int)
    val original = List(3) { a ->
        List(3) { b ->
            IntHolder(a + b)
        }
    }

    val copied = original.deepCopy2 { it.copy() }
    original[0][0].value = 18258125
    println("original=$original")
    println("copied  =$copied")
}
```

->

```
original=[[IntHolder(value=18258125), IntHolder(value=1), IntHolder(value=2)], [IntHolder(value=1), IntHolder(value=2), IntHolder(value=3)], [IntHolder(value=2), IntHolder(value=3), IntHolder(value=4)]]
copied  =[[IntHolder(value=0), IntHolder(value=1), IntHolder(value=2)], [IntHolder(value=1), IntHolder(value=2), IntHolder(value=3)], [IntHolder(value=2), IntHolder(value=3), IntHolder(value=4)]]
```

---

[1]: Because generic type casts are performed by the compiler at runtime, a cast from `List<Foo>` to `List<Baz>` will always succeed at runtime, but fail later upon access of the casted list. Implementing mentioned magic "single function" is possible, but the slightest of error would result in a returned data structure that fails seemingly "random" upon access with class cast exceptions.

[2]: A value of type `Iterable<Iterable<Foo>>` satisfies both

`fun <T> Iterable<T>.baz()` (T = `Iterable<Foo>`) and
`fun <T> Iterable<Iterable<T>.baz()` (T = `Foo`)

Due to this, the compiler would not be able to determine the right method to use if all methods in the chain have the same function name, but different JVM names.

[3]:

```
Iterable<Iterable<Iterable<Iterable<Iterable<Iterable<Iterable<Iterable<Iterable<Iterable<Iterable<Iterable<Iterable<Iterable<Iterable<Iterable<Iterable<Iterable<Iterable<Iterable<Iterable<Iterable<Iterable<Iterable<Iterable<Iterable<Iterable<Iterable<Iterable<Iterable<Iterable<Iterable<Iterable<Iterable<Iterable<Iterable<Iterable<Iterable<Iterable<Iterable<Iterable<Iterable<Iterable<Iterable<Iterable<Iterable<Iterable<Iterable<Iterable<Iterable<ithinkyougetthepoint>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
```

Comment: why did you repeat yourself? serializing & deserializing is for deep copy very well in java.

Comment: Given OPs initial attempt, I figured serialization is out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple deep copy example by using [java.lang.reflect.Array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html) & [java.lang.Cloneable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html).

*Noet*: the [clone](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone--)  method performs a **shallow** copy of this object, not a **deep** copy operation, but you can override the [clone](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone--) method to provide a **deep** copy operation, for example:

```
val list = mutableListOf(mutableListOf(arrayOf(1)))
val copied = list.deepCopy()

println(copied !== list) //true: not the same
println(copied.map{it.map{it.toList()}} == list.map{it.map{it.toList()}}) 
//                                      ^---true: content equals

//                v--- Array is cloned, since it has implemented Cloneable
println(copied[0][0] !== array[0][0]) // true
```

---

```
typealias NativeArray = java.lang.reflect.Array
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
fun <T> T.deepCopy(): T {
    return when (this) {
        is Array<*> -> {
            val type = this.javaClass.componentType
            NativeArray.newInstance(type, size).also {
                this.forEachIndexed { i, item ->
                    NativeArray.set(it, i, item.deepCopy())
                }
            } as T
        }
        is MutableList<*> -> this.mapTo(mutableListOf()) { it.deepCopy() } as T
        is List<*> -> this.map { it.deepCopy() } as T
        is Cloneable -> this.javaClass.getDeclaredMethod("clone").let {
            it.isAccessible = true;
            it.invoke(this) as T
        }
        else -> this
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not really sure if this is in scope of the question, given that OP asked for copying a 2D *list* and not arrays. If you're bringing in cloning and `java.lang.reflect.Array`, might aswell serialize the object via ObjectOutputStream->ByteArrayOutputStream->ByteArrayInputStream->ObjectInputStream, but this forces all objects to be Serializable..

Comment: @mEQ5aNLrK3lqs3kfSa5HbvsTWe0nIu how about it now?